# SwingWorker setting a flag after finishing its work

Tags: java, swing, swingworker

I have put together an application that opens text files and allows users to edit them (eg: text editor)

Some text files can be arbitrarily large, so it would take some time to open them. I have added a progress bar to inform the user that stuff is actually happening, and am using a swing worker to perform the actual file loading, giving it a reference to a text area to dump all the text.

I also have a flag in the main application called `isFileLoaded` which is true if there's a file open, and false otherwise. Ideally, the swing worker should set that value after it finishes loading the file and doing any processing that it needs to do.

I have written the swing worker as a separate class, so it's not nested inside my main Frame class that holds all of the GUI logic, mainly because I do not like to define classes inside classes purely for aesthetic reasons. As such, I am currently passing a reference to the entire Frame to the swing worker and letting it set the value of the flag.

Is this a good way to do things? Are there better ways?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider rather adding a `PropertyChangeListener` which holds a reference to your `Frame` (an anonymous inner-class would be just fine for that matter) and which listens to the `"state"` property. The value of the event will be equal to `StateValue.DONE` when the `SwingWorker` has finished.

Here is a fully working example:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker.StateValue;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class TestSwingWorker {

    private JProgressBar progressBar;

    protected void initUI() {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle(TestSwingWorker.class.getSimpleName());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JButton button = new JButton("Clik me to start work");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                doWork();
            }
        });
        progressBar = new JProgressBar(0, 100);
        frame.add(progressBar, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private boolean someFlag;

    protected void doWork() {
        SwingWorker<Void, Integer> worker = new SwingWorker<Void, Integer>() {
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
                for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                    // Simulates work
                    Thread.sleep(10);
                    publish(i);
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void process(List<Integer> chunks) {
                progressBar.setValue(chunks.get(chunks.size() - 1));
            }

            @Override
            protected void done() {
                progressBar.setValue(100);
                progressBar.setStringPainted(true);
                progressBar.setString("Done");
            }
        };
        worker.getPropertyChangeSupport().addPropertyChangeListener("state", new PropertyChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
                if (StateValue.DONE.equals(evt.getNewValue())) {
                    someFlag = true;
                }
            }
        });
        worker.execute();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException,
            UnsupportedLookAndFeelException {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new TestSwingWorker().initUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not familiar with listeners, though after reading some swing tutorials it looks like if I really want to get some responsive applications I'll need to start working with them. Can you provide some snippets showing where I would be adding the listener and how the swing worker will work with it?

Answer (score 1):

You should restructure your code a little to avoid using the whole Frame which indeed is not really clean (but if it works who cares).

If you want to be more cool from a design point of view you should use a model:

```
class FileModel
{
    boolean isLoading;
    // getter and setter that notifies
}
```

and pass only this model to your worker, and once done set the flag.

Comment: Having an object shared between multiple components sounds like a good idea, since I can uniformly access the data from various objects and provide an additional layer of abstraction.

Comment: This is the essence of the MVC pattern and all its derivatives: separate concerns: view on one side, logic and data on another side. :)